# Reactor - single threaded stateful transfomation

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, thread-safety, project-reactor

I'm building a processing pipeline that consumes events, applies stateful transformation and saves the result in the database.

To be more specific, the consumer reads series of events, then I need to hold them (in memory) until specific events comes (so called 'end-of-batch') and then transform them. Transformation is stateful - logic depends on the order of events received previously.

This could be described by following Kotlin pseudocode:

```
val consumer: QueueConsumer<Event> = Consumer()
consumer.read()
   .concatMap { events: List<Event> -> Monojust(transformer.transform(events)}
   .concatMap {db.saveAll(it}
```

My question is, how to approach the threading of the `transformer`. My idea is to have it single threaded to avoid synchronization.

The consumer is a single thread busy spinning on and filesystem read, hence `transformer.transform(events)` runs always in the consumer thread.

Actually, I'd considered this design as not very robust as it depends on the threading of the upstream operator and works only in assumption that it's single threaded.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you consider using the bufferUntil method of Flux? That would take care of handling the state so you don't have to.